# Are there debug tools for express in visual studio code?

Tags: express, visual-studio-code

Is there a debug tool for Express in VSCode?

I'm logging messages to the console but I'd rather set breakpoints and step through the code.

For example,
[image]

Comment: Debugging node should work out of the box in VSCode. Just add a breakpoint anywhere in your program before running it throught VSCode **Run and Debug**. If there are problems with that, it'd be good to add more details to the question.

Comment: @DorinBotan When I pressed the debug button it told me it needed a launch file to debug.but there could be something I missed. When creating a launch config it did say something about not being able to auto detect the project type so that might be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does support it.

Though it says that it needs a launch config, although others have said it works for them without a launch config.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

This is what was shown in the debug view:

[image]

It looks like there are instructions on creating a launch config here.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

It basically says to click the "Create launch config" link and then select Node.js from the list.

[image]

Since Express is a library that runs in node js, getting debug support in node js is also getting debug support for express.

Thanks me. Good job.